# Statistics for multicore memory accesses

Tags: memory, multicore, simulator, latency

Soes anybody know any simulator that I can use in order to measure statistics of memory access latencies for multicore processors?

Are there such statistics(for any kind of multicore) already published somewhere?

Comment: There's a small list here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441667/implementing-a-cache-modeling-framework/20441826#20441826

Answer (score 0):

You might try CodeAnalyst from AMD which monitors the performance registers during program execution on AMD processors. Multi-core too where applicable.

I don't know the name of intel's equivalent product.