# Show cpu cache and register contents during debugging

Tags: c++, memory-management, visualization, cpu-registers, cpu-cache

I have a piece of software which uses complex data structures and I would like to understand how the program utilizes the different caches and registers.

*Question*:

- Is there some debugger-like software which shows **at a breakpoint** not only the program flow, but also the contents of the registers, the caches and main memory?
- Perhaps in a graphical form: so that, when I **select a variable, it shows representations in different caches/registers** highlighted?

I am currently using Visual Studio, therefore a plugin would be preferred, but the program compiles with gcc.

---

Edit: the profilers like CodeAnalyst and CacheGrind seem to do this kind of thing only after program execution, in the way a profiler would do, but I am more interested in understanding the step-by-step execution behaviour.

Example

```
Code Line 1;  // break here and show which variables are currently stored where.
Code Line 2;
for(int i=0; i<some_var; i++) {
    Code Line 3;  // break here and compare cache contents.
}
```

Comment: As for caches, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) have some [tools](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) for that.

Comment: You may use [CacheGrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have improved the question. Based on the documentation it seems CacheGrind shows average behaviour but not the current cache contents during debugging.

Comment: @AbhiP The documenation of CacheGrind says it collects statistics using a model of the caches. Do you know of a tool that shows current cache utilization during debugging? Perhaps in a play-back manner?

Comment: Yes, you can try [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html). I have used it earlier and it creates the diagrams that reflect your programming stack/calls so it is relatively easy to understand once you have set it up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to look directly into the cache state during runtime, since the act of looking, especially if breakpoints are involved, or some code that would manage this inspection, would greatly impact on the cache state, practically destroying what you were trying to inspect. Worse - that's assuming you could get some kind of cache picture or dump using some simple code - which is not the case.

In fact, even if you were to magically get a picture of the cache state at a given moment, it's not likely to mean anything after a few micro seconds since page mapping may constantly differ, lines get fetched and thrown out of the cache all the time, and the entire cache may be flushed. In fact, the core or the CPU may even stop for a short powerdown, automatically flushing anything in the cache in the process.

Here are 3 ways to review the cache context in a non-intrusive way:

- Use a simulator that can present that state at any given moment. There are various cache and CPU simulators out there, I mentioned a few here - [Implementing a cache modeling framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441667/implementing-a-cache-modeling-framework/20441826#20441826)

the downside is that none of these can guarantee to regenerate the exact same scenario you have on your real CPU. A cache simulator isn't realistic as it simplifies all accesses to a single linear stream, ignoring for e.g. the ones in the real CPU that got flushed due to branch mispredictions. The lack of timing element may also change the way the replacement policy behaves, and give you different results. It's not likely to be a problem, it should make a difference only on real corner cases, but just keep that in mind. Timing simulators are more realistic and would have better chances to reproduce your issues, but none of the available ones will necessarily model the exact same micro-architecture your CPU has. You may be able to configure them to be as close as possible though.

- Use internal CPU performance counters to track cache related statistics. This gives you the real picture, but unfortunately provides less visibility, definitely not at realtime. Some profilers (including Vtune and the likes of it) can do the dirty work for you and present these statistics sampled over time, which may be more useful.
- Add dedicated code that gets called programmatically when you want to check the cache contents. This code can then perform some (limited) checks, like guessing if a certain line exists in the cache using a timed lookup. It's quite complicated but may suit better if you look for specific lines there. I just noticed I wrote in a non-intrusive way - scratch that, this way is of course very intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CodeAnalyst from AMD (free) or VTune from Intel (payware, but with free trial). Both are graphical, unlike Valgrind

Comment: thanks, I have edited the question. The way I understand it, is that CodeAnalyst gives an average cache hit/miss behaviour for a variable. Can it also show me during program execution how the caches look like?

Comment: kcachegrind - gui frontend for cachegrind